# I don't want word to change certain cross references on update

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, bookmarks, cross-reference, reference-book

I'm using a special reference system that no one uses except these people I'm writing for. It uses a system of brackets, for instance "[ABC]" would be a reference. I guess other reference systems use brackets but I can't use any of the existing once in Word, since there is certain formatting depending on if it's a book and so on.

I'm currently using a table with the references to the right and the labels, i.e. "[ABC]" to the left. I want to cross reference from other places in the document to the position of the label in table.

I've tried creating a bookmark for each of the reference and then a cross reference at the place in the text I want it on. Then I change the label to let's say "[ABC, p. 123]". But when I update the entire document it switches all the cross references back to what the bookmark says, in this case: "[ABC, p. 123]" -> "[ABC]".

Does anyone know a nice way of solving this? It would be great if you could mark some cross references as "do not update/change".

Of course I could avoid updating the entire document and just what I need to update (table of content, etc.), but that is not a fool proof method since I'm using other cross references which I want to be up-to-date. Also if I fail, all the reference are switched back to normal and I have to (if I remember) go through every reference and see which page in the book I found the referenced information on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just manually editing the cross-reference field text, then yes it will update when fields are refreshed and revert back to the original text.  Instead, for your  bookmarks, don't include the [] ie just bookmark the text.  For your cross-reference, you would type the [ then insert a cross-reference to the bookmark TEXT then type your comma and p. and then insert a second cross-reference to the bookmark page, then type your closing square bracket.  Now when your fields update, if the title of the label has changed or the pagination has changed, both the label and page number will automatically update for you.